# soundManager.createsound() without using direct URL

Tags: soundmanager2

https://www.speaklanguages.com/english/phrases/more-common-expressions
So this website use SoundManager to play the audio. The required format to create sound is

> Creates a sound with the specified ID and URL (simple two-parameter
>   method.) Example:
>   `soundManager.createSound('mySound','/audio/mysoundfile.mp3');`

However, when I check the source code of the site, it's something like this

```
soundManager.createSound('en','im_going_out_f');
```

The actual sound URL is http://speaklanguages.cachefly.net/sound/en/mp3/im_going_out_f.mp3

So can someone please explain to me that how was that possible to include just the name of the file instead of the whole mp3 link?

Comment: Relative URLs - probably best to check out the answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2005079/6340326

Comment: Not sure if it is relative URL because "im_going_out_f" is without file type. And the JS file is also in a different folder to the mp3 file.